# Show text box after choose in drop down list

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, textbox

Just wanna ask u guys here, I have a drop down list box which stored elements; A and B. When user choose A, it will display 5 text boxes in the same page. It will only display when user select A and B. Hit the answer answer or comment button if u have an idea of how to do it. Thnks and have a nice day!

Comment: What will happen if you choose B?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: downvoted for a very unclear question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "A")
    {
        TextBox1.Visible = true;
        TextBox2.Visible = true;
        TextBox3.Visible = true;
        TextBox4.Visible = true;
        TextBox5.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    { 
        // do something
    }

}
```

By default, make sure you set the `Visible` property of the `Textbox` controls to `False`.
Enable the `AutoPostBack` of the `DropDownList` control to `True`.

Comment: Hey, why when i click B, the textboxes are not shown? A and B are supposedly display the textbox. If user not choose anything, textbox is invi. Thnks

Comment: This only displays the text boxes when the user selects a choice and submits the form if there is a submit button, I don't think this answers the question @aemy you shouldn't of accepted this as a right answer before trying it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in two ways.

By using javascript:

Your textboxs are included in the markup with `dispaly:none;` and upon dropdownselect there display property is set to block.

```
DropDownList.Attributes.Add("onChange", "return OnSelectedIndexChange();") 
function OnSelectedIndexChange()

{
document.getElementById("TextBox1").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("TextBox2").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("TextBox3").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("TextBox4").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("TextBox5").style.display="block";
}
```

By using AJAX:

Your textboxs have `visible="false"` initially and upon dropdownselect change their property `visible="true"`.

```
protected void DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList.SelectedItem.Text == "A")
    {
        TextBox1.Visible = true;
        TextBox2.Visible = true;
        TextBox3.Visible = true;
        TextBox4.Visible = true;
        TextBox5.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    { 
        // do something
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

string txt = this.DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

 switch (txt)
            {
                case "A":
                  TextBox1.Visible = true;
                  TextBox2.Visible = true;
                  TextBox3.Visible = true;
                  TextBox4.Visible = true;
                  TextBox5.Visible = true;
                    break;
                case "do something":
                   do something
                    break;


            }
}
```

with the help of using switch case you can able to add as many conditions as many you want.